# Dropdown is not listing French characters

Tags: php, html

I have a dropdown list, which lists things that has french characters in it. Although I see characters like this:  [image]

MySQL database is set to UTF-8. So, there is no problem in database. I've checked the database and characters are okay.

I also added these lines to my header.php but still doesn't work.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

What else should I do?

**EDIT**
I can print french letters everywhere in the site but still dropdown doesn't work.

**SOLUTION**
First of all, if you would like to use utf-8 in your site you should add this right after you connect to database:

```
mysqli_set_charset($connectionName, 'utf8mb4');
```

Second, you should also add this in your header tags:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

That's all. After all these, my problem still wasn't fixed until I figure out my stupidity. I have header.php file, which is included on top of every page but there is another php file, which outputs dropbox options from database. So, this file don't need header.php at top. So, I had to add mysqli_set_charset($connectionName, 'utf8mb4'); specially for that page.

Comment: and what about your connection?

Comment: This may fall as a duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: No! Oh I read about it yesterday. Everybody forgets that =) Yes that might be the problem? But how do we do it?

Comment: *"No! Oh I read about it yesterday. Everybody forgets that"* - Sorry, I wasn't at that meeting ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- this is how I connect:     $dbConnection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/ from the link I already gave you. It shows you how to pass UTF-8 through your connection and query. and http://stackoverflow.com/a/30063664/

Comment: @Fred-ii- looks like this isn't the problem. After I connect to database I added charset function; $dbConnection = open_connection();
mysqli_set_charset($dbConnection, 'utf8mb4'); And I also added meta tags too

Comment: well, check to see if your file was indeed "saved as" an UTF-8 format. Far too many things can be contributing to its failure, and I mean *far too many*.